# SQLite INSERT OR REPLACE only inserts and never replaces

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, sql-update, android-sqlite

My INSERT OR REPLACE query doesn't seem to work. It only inserts values to database but never update. I would like it to check for the date, if it finds the same date then it will just update the values and not insert a new line.

Here is my query:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> s=contentValues.valueSet();
                Iterator itr = s.iterator();
                String[] valuesArray;
                List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
                    Object value =  me.getValue();
                    valuesList.add(String.valueOf(value));
                }
                valuesArray = valuesList.toArray(new String[valuesList.size()]);

                Date unformatedDate = new Date(valuesArray[2]);
                SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String formatedDate = DATE_FORMAT.format(unformatedDate);
                valuesArray[2] = formatedDate;

                db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO history (_id, totalElevation, datetime, totaldistance, averageSpeed) VALUES ((SELECT _id FROM history WHERE datetime = ?),?,?,?,?)", valuesArray);
```

And here is my table structure:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "datetime DATE, " +
            "totaldistance DOUBLE, " +
            "totalElevation DOUBLE," +
            "averageSpeed DOUBLE" +
            ");");
```

Comment: sqlite sorry ... well it is in the title

Comment: What is the actual date value used in the subquery? Does it exist in the database?

Comment: you need to make datetime UNIQUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the date to the wrong placeholder the **third** (`valuesArray[2]`), instead of the **first** (`valuesArray[0]`).

The parameters are **positional**.
There's a 1:1 relation between the position in the query or in the command and the position in the array (which indices start from **0**).

Your SQL command (again, it's not a query - queries are only `SELECT`) will be resolved as something like this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO history (_id, totalElevation, datetime, totaldistance, averageSpeed) VALUES 
    ((SELECT _id FROM history WHERE datetime = A), B, '2016-12-23', C, D)
```

Where A is in valuesArray[0], B is in valuesArray[1], '2016-12-23' is in valuesArray[2], C is in valuesArray[3], D is in valuesArray[4]

While you need a command which looks like this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO history (_id, totalElevation, datetime, totaldistance, averageSpeed) VALUES 
    ((SELECT _id FROM history WHERE datetime = '2016-12-23'), A, B, C, D)
```

Where '2016-12-23' is in valuesArray[0], A is in valuesArray[1], B is in valuesArray[2], C is in valuesArray[3], D is in valuesArray[4]